# ¿Qué quiere decir "pilas" en Colombia?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, colombia, interjecciones

Leía el otro día una noticia en el periódico El Tiempo de Colombia: [Mapa: Pilas con las ciclorrutas donde más roban bicicletas en Bogotá](http://www.eltiempo.com/bogota/lugares-donde-mas-roban-bicicletas-en-bogota-64814). Bajo el subtítulo *Reconozca los lugares que señalan como los más peligrosos para los biciusuarios*, menciona las zonas de Bogotá donde más robos se producen.

Además del uso de *biciusuarios* (¿será lo mismo que ciclista?), me gustó lo de "pilas" a modo de atención.

Busqué en el Diccionario de americanismos e inicialmente encontré esta segunda acepción específica de Colombia (la primera tiene muchísimas acepciones):

> [**pilo, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=NB97aY3wTx0A73dHRdH%7CEElzjuYMSx0AvbsctZb).
>   I.  1.  adj/sust. Co:C,O. Referido a persona, hábil, diligente, juiciosa. pop + cult. ◆ piloso.

Donde *Co:C,O* entiendo que se refiere a *Colombia: Central y Oeste*. Luego vi que también existe la entrada para la interjección:

> [**¡pilas!**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=SfJEuAEJgx0A5vFYIs2%7CMMESdsQaGx0AqDoHFyu)
>   I.  1.  interj. Gu, Ho, Co; Ec, juv. Expresa atención, vigilancia o alerta.

Que aplicaría a Guatemala, Honduras, Colombia y Ecuador (a ver si añaden ya la leyenda al pasar el ratón por encima...).

Total, que parece que con "pilas" en la noticia estaban alertando a los ciclistas sobre los lugares más inseguros en cuanto a robos. Pero una vez resuelta la curiosidad, me viene la siguiente: ¿Qué sentido tiene "pilas" exactamente en la noticia? ¿Se usa como interjección en este caso? ¿De dónde viene el uso de "pilas" en los sentidos descritos por el diccionario de americanismos? ¿Por qué la interjección se entiende en unos cuantos países, mientras que el adjetivo solamente en Colombia?

Comment: Pero en el artículo no parece ser usada como interjección, sino como sustantivo, y las acepciones como sustantivo no me cuadran con lo que dice el diccionario... Me suena más a acepción moderna no recogida aún.

Comment: Buscando en el CREA he visto que en Colombia se usa la expresión [*ponerse las pilas*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sz7DDE4#EhunN5q). La interjección podría venir directamente de ahí, dado que a una persona descuidada o despistada se le puede decir "¡ponte las pilas!", y de ahí se haya simplificado a "¡pilas!". Lo que ya no sé es si su uso como sustantivo proviene también de ahí o no.

Comment: También aplicaría para México, el *ponerse las pilas* toma un sentido de estar alerta a lo que pasa a los alrededores; como ejemplo: cuando algún juguete se le ponen pilas nuevas inmediatamente tiene un desempeño mucho mejor y todo le funciona a la perfección. Ahora, diciendo que te pongas la pilas también significa debes tomar atención y que todos tus sentidos deben estar alerta. Algo similar sería decir *aguas* o *abusado*, aunque no estoy seguro si estos *sinonimos* también sean conocidos en otros países. Otro sentido sería que te *actives* y seas proactivo.

Comment: En Argentina también se usa "ponerse las pilas" en el sentido de ponerse en acción o en movimiento, en contraposición a "dejarse estar". También usamos - desde ya, en registro coloquial - "estar pila" o "estar re pila", como sinónimo de activo, entusiasmado, e inclusive optimista.

Comment: Sin duda es una simplificación desafortunada de  «ponerse las pilas».  En España también es una expresión común.  Lo que me deja ojiplático es que «biciusuarios» no es la ocurrencia de un periodista, sino una palabra corriente en Bogotá. Curioso.

Comment: El término "biciusuario" lo inventaron en oposición a "usuarios del transporte público" para referirse a las personas "usuarios de la bicicleta" como **medio de transporte** para desplazarse a sus lugares de trabajo y/o estudio, mientras que _ciclista_ tiene la connotación del uso deportivo de la bicicleta. Asociado al _biciusuario_ también tenemos la **cicloruta** que son corredores anexos a las vías por donde deben circular los _biciusuarios_. Efectivamente son dos palabras compuestas **inventadas**

Comment: En Chile traduciríamos "¡pilas con las luces rojas!" por "¡ojo con las luces rojas!".

Comment: En la sala de espera un aeropuerto en México hace varios años, un señor comentó,  *Su hijo tiene much pila*.  Se refería al nivel de energía de mi hijo, que tenía unos dos años en aquel entonces..  No sé si el señor era mexicano, pero entendí su idea de inmediato.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Los juguetes no funcionan hasta que uno les "pone las pilas" de ahí aparece la expresión con el sentido de *activarse o ponerse activo/atento*

La expresión **ponerse las pilas** en el sentido de *entrar en acción* es muy usada en Colombia y de ahí se derivan tanto la interjección como el adjetivo.

El adjetivo en realidad solo es usado de manera frecuente en Bogotá y sus alrededores y no es muy usado en toda Colombia de manera general aunque se entiende gracias a los medios/noticieros/telenovelas originados en la capital del país.

El origen del adjetivo es simple: pereza/eficiencia/simplificación. En lugar de decir la larga frase "esa persona se mantiene con las pilas puestas" queriendo decir *esa persona es muy activa/alerta y siempre esta listo para actuar* es más simple decir **Esa persona es muy pila** y de ahí el masculino y el femenino **El niño es muy pilo** / **La niña es muy pila**

En el contexto de la noticia efectivamente es la interjección y significa **¡Alerta¡ ¡No se duerma! No dé papaya que le roban la bici**.

---

<sub>Con respecto a la palabra compuesta Biciusuario:</sub>

<sub>El término "biciusuario" lo inventaron en oposición a "usuarios del transporte público" para referirse a las personas "usuarios de la bicicleta" como **medio de transporte** para desplazarse a sus lugares de trabajo y/o estudio, mientras que *ciclista* tiene la connotación del uso deportivo de la bicicleta. Asociado al *biciusuario* también tenemos la **cicloruta** que son corredores anexos a las vías por donde deben circular los *biciusuarios*. Efectivamente son dos palabras compuestas **inventadas**</sub>

Comment: Fantástico. En España (y por lo que veo en los comentarios, en casi todos los países de habla hispana) se usa la expresión _ponerse las pilas_, es interesante ver que en Colombia rizasteis el rizo y lo simplificasteis a _pilas_ a secas.

Comment: *¿No dé papaya?*

Comment: @aparente001, No dé oportunidad, No se "ponga en bandeja de plata". "Dar Papaya" suele ser usado para cuando alguien puede aprovecharse de una situación por descuido o por ingenuidad, siendo la víctima culpable de "dar papaya". Si usted  usó una de las ciclorutas peligrosas a pesar de ser advertido y lo robaron, usted "dió papaya".